# Symfony - Is it possible to edit twig templates using web editor

Tags: php, symfony, twig

We have a website that is built on top of Symfony framework and I have been given a task of allowing the admins to make changes to the email templates or even the twig templates via admin panel like in WordPress where you go to the editor and make changes to the files.

I know Symfony is not a CMS and I am wondering **if allowing admins to edit email templates and other twig templates is at all possible to do**. The templates are not saved in database they are in their normal location `NameBundle/Resources/views` **and as we know on production Symfony uses cache.**

While searching online I came across [Ace](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=about) editor and [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/) but again I am stuck at how to use anything like this with Symfony

I will really appreciate if anyone can push me in right direction.

Comment: Since twig templates are plain files, you could always write a code that will file_get_contents(), then modify, and then put it back in using file_put_contents() or similar file read/write functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same need recently.

I chose to put the edited content in a `app/Resources/AcmeBundle/views/Include/menu.html.twig` file because I didn't want to put this in a Bundle. A file `src/AcmeBundle/Resources/views/Include/menu.html.twig` is loaded the first time this page is loaded, its content will be used as a basis for the editable Twig template. The file can also be empty.

### Controller's function:

```
 /**
 * @Route(
 *      "/edit/menu",
 *      name = "page_edit_menu"
 * )
 */
public function editMenuAction(Request $request)
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ADMIN', null, 'Access denied.');

    // Output file.
    $filepath = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').
        '/Resources/AcmeBundle/views/Include/menu.html.twig';

    // Dummy object used in the form.
    $file = new \ArrayObject();

    // Check that the output file exists.
    if (file_exists($filepath)) {
        // Load the file content.
        $file->content = file_get_contents($filepath);
    } else {
        // The file is missing, load the file located in the Bundle instead.
        $file->content = file_get_contents(
            $this->container->get('kernel')->locateResource(
            '@AcmeBundle/Resources/views/Include/menu.html.twig')
        );
    }

    // Declare the form.
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($file)
        // A textarea for the file content.
        ->add('content', 'textarea', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'rows' => 16,
            )
        ))
        ->add('submit', 'submit', array(
            'label' => 'Save'
        ))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        // Save the file in app/Resources/...
        file_put_contents($filepath, $file->content);

        // Clear cache (otherwise the changes won't be applied)
        // Be patient, it can take about 15 seconds.
        $console = 'php '.$this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').
            '/console';

        exec($console.' cache:clear --env=prod');
        exec($console.' cache:warmup --env=prod');

        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice',
            'Content saved succesfully.');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('page_edit_menu'));
    }

    return $this->render('editMenu.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

### Twig file

The associated Twig file `editMenu.html.twig` only contain the form:

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

### Usage

Here is how the editable template is used where you want to display the file previously edited:

```
{% include('AcmeBundle:Include:menu.html.twig') %}
```

Thanks to [templates overriding](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates), the `app/Resources/AcmeBundle/views/Include/menu.html.twig` file will be used instead of the one in the Bundle.

### Git

If you use git, you have to add the file path in the `.gitignore` file:

```
# File that can be edited from the admin:
/app/Resources/AcmeBundle/views/Include/menu.html.twig
```

Without this, an update with git may alter or delete this file.

### HTML editor

If you want a WYSIWYG editor, you can install [TinymceBundle](https://github.com/stfalcon/TinymceBundle) which provide an HTML editor. Here is a quick guide to use it if you already have jQuery. Otherwise follow the documentation.

```
composer require "stfalcon/tinymce-bundle:dev-master"
```

A simple configuration to add to `app/config/config.yml`:

```
stfalcon_tinymce:
    selector: ".tinymce"
    language: %locale%
    theme:
        simple:
            theme: "modern"
            plugins: "link"
            toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic | bullist numlist outdent indent | link"
```

And add `'class' => 'tinymce',` after `'rows' => 16,` and `{{ tinymce_init() }}` in your Javascript.

Comment: This is so kind of you to share, I will go through these and get back to you

Comment: Can you please explain to me the section of `Twig file` and `Usage`, my understanding is that inside `app/Resources/AcmeBundle/views/Include/menu.html.twig` I only need to have the `{{ form(form) }}` but then where do i put `{% include('AcmeBundle:Include:menu.html.twig') %}`

Comment: @Saadia I updated my answer. You put `{% include('AcmeBundle:Include:menu.html.twig') %}` where you want to show the file.

Comment: Just be aware that clearing the cache on your production server whenever you update a template can cause unpleasant surprises for your users.  Also be aware that updating files under Resources can have source code control issues.  Be a shame to lose all your changes the next time composer update is run.

Comment: @Cerad thanks for the interesting comment. Should the cache refresh be done only when needed instead of every time the file is refreshed? With a different button for example? I added a note about git.

Comment: @A.L - The basic problem is that you do need to refresh the cache whenever a template file is updated in order for the changes to be seen.  I have never tried to implement this sort of solution.  If faced with a similar task I would look at some of the existing cms solutions and see what they do.  I would definitely store changed template files in a dedicated directory (or a database).  And then figure how to update just the twig cache.

Comment: @Cerad are you suggesting to refresh the cache of this file only? That's a nice idea but I don't know how to do this. Since it's included in other files, maybe it won't refresh everything? Do Twig include files on the fly or insert the included file when creating the cache?

Comment: @A.L - All good questions to which I don't know the answer.  Twig 'compiles' the templates into php.  You can look in the cache directory to get an idea of the results.  I'm fairly confident you can have twig compile a single template but I'd have to research to determine the details.  Hence the notion of seeing how other people do it.

Comment: many thanks for the valuable input, i am looking into this and i will get back max by tomorrow :) once again thanks alot.

Comment: Perhaps one can put the website under maintenance mode while making changes and once all done then turn off the maintenance mode this way users do not face any unpleasant browsing experience.

Comment: I was able to get the output I needed :) a million thanks

Comment: createBuildForm  should be initiated with  $file not $fichier, but the edit is to small to go through

Comment: @alexseif Thanks for reporting this, I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 4):

Twig lets you use [multiple template loaders](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#loaders) where you can have templates stored as string instead of files. One of the examples shows probably exactly what you need. They're using [strings as templates](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#twig-loader-chain).

I think this feature has changed recently because I remember there used to be [`Twig_Loader_String` class](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/api/v1.14.0/Twig_Loader_String.html). It looks like it's been removed since `1.15`.

In your case you store templates in the database and then add them to the filter chain just like here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#twig-loader-chain

Symfony configuration has also [`twig.loader`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#twig-loader) tag for adding new loaders.

Comment: Two Martins... it's taken a while on here, but now StackOverflow has confused me. hah

Comment: @Martin(s) :) many thanks for that, I will have a look into these resources, any idea how to display these in web editor and update them when saved via admin panel?

Comment: I don't use Wordpress so I don't know. Anyway, editing and storing temples is unrelated to Twig. You can do it in any way you want.